# discord.py Why does if statement and else statement at the same time?

Tags: python-3.x, if-statement, discord.py

I have a discord bot written in python and I'm trying to create command to make say command with blacklisted messages (the annoying things). It supposed to give the error message and for  some reason the if and else statements both are executing. Why it it happening? What am i doing wrong?

I have tried adding `break` `pass` and it still did the else statement

Here's my current code for the command:

```py
@client.command()
async def say(ctx, *, message):
    if message == '@everyone':
        await ctx.message.delete()
        await ctx.send('Do not abuse this command')
    if message == '@here':
        await ctx.message.delete()
        await ctx.send('Do not abuse this command')
    for role in ctx.guild.roles:
        if message == f'<@&{role.id}>':
            await ctx.message.delete()
            await ctx.send('Nice try but do not abuse this command')
    else:
        await ctx.send(message)
        await ctx.message.delete()
        print(f'{ctx.message.author} ({ctx.author.id}) in {ctx.guild.name} ({ctx.guild.id}) made me say: {message}')
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems in your code. The first one is that after your `if`s, the code doesn't leave the function, so it will running the code.

In addition, the `else` keyword is related to the `for` loop, so the behavior is as explained here:
https://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/for_-_else.html. But basically the `else` isn't related to the `if`s above.

What you'd like to achieve is probably something like this:

```py
@client.command()
async def say(ctx, *, message):
    if message == '@everyone':
        await ctx.message.delete()
        await ctx.send('Do not abuse this command')
    elif message == '@here':
        await ctx.message.delete()
        await ctx.send('Do not abuse this command')
    elif:
        for role in ctx.guild.roles:
            if message == f'<@&{role.id}>':
                await ctx.message.delete()
                await ctx.send('Nice try but do not abuse this command')
    else:
        await ctx.send(message)
        await ctx.message.delete()
        print(f'{ctx.message.author} ({ctx.author.id}) in {ctx.guild.name} ({ctx.guild.id}) made me say: {message}')
```